# Displaying an image stored in a Django database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a website dedicated to pets (dead ones), and I have some stock images in the database stored under the pet using a manytomany field (so, any number of pets can be in an image, and a pet can have any number of images associated with it--seems logical so far). I am trying to display the pet photos in any way at all in one of the templates.

My problem is, I have no idea of the correct syntax for iterating over a `context_dictionary data structure I have made to store pets and pet photos for the purpose of accessing in the associated template file. I am having to do this because I think (correct me if I'm wrong) a view can only have one associated model, and I need a few models, their data, to display in one view. So. It is what it is.

I think it's probably about time I showed some of my code. Here is one after another:

pet_profile/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
import uuid
from django.urls import reverse

class PetPhoto(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 5, primary_key = True, blank = True, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 261, default=uuid.uuid1)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank = False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
        slug_save(self)
        get_ID2(self)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class PetStory(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 5, primary_key = True, blank = True, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    content = models.TextField(max_length = 1000)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
        slug_save(self)
        get_ID(self)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "PetStories"


ANIMALTYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('dog', 'the one that barks'),
    ('cat', 'the one that meows'),
    ('lizard', 'the one that eats crickets'),
    ('snake', 'the one that slithers'),
    ('rabbit/bunny', 'the one that hops'),
    ('bird', 'the one that flaps'),
    ('fish', 'the one that swims'),
    ('frog', 'the one that croaks'),
)

class Pet(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 5, primary_key = True, blank = True, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = False)
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 261, unique = True, default = uuid.uuid1)
    animaltype = models.CharField(choices = ANIMALTYPE_CHOICES, max_length = 255, default="the one that barks")
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pet_photos = models.ManyToManyField(PetPhoto, related_name = "pets", blank = True)
    pet_stories = models.ManyToManyField(PetStory, related_name = "pets", blank = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
        slug_save(self)
        get_ID(self)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class PetOwner(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 5, primary_key = True, blank = True, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 261, unique = True, default=uuid.uuid1)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(blank = True)
    pets = models.ManyToManyField(Pet, related_name = "Owners")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("owner_profile", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})  

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
        slug_save(self)
        get_ID(self)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def slug_save(obj):
    """ A function to generate a 5 character slug and see if it has been used and contains naughty words."""
    if not obj.slug: # if there isn't a slug
        obj.slug = get_random_string(5) # create one
        slug_is_wrong = True  
        while slug_is_wrong: # keep checking until we have a valid slug
            slug_is_wrong = False
            other_objs_with_slug = type(obj).objects.filter(slug=obj.slug)
            if len(other_objs_with_slug) > 0:
                # if any other objects have current slug
                slug_is_wrong = True
            #if predict(obj.slug):
            #    slug_is_wrong = True
            if slug_is_wrong:
                # create another slug and check it again
                obj.slug = get_random_string(5)

def get_ID(obj):
    obj.id = obj.name + '-' + obj.slug

def get_ID2(obj):
    obj.id = obj.title + '-' + obj.slug
```

Of relevance are Pet and PetPhoto. Pay attention to those. Notice that Pet stores associated pet_photos in a manytomany field, and afaik you don't need to reverse the data interaction--you can just access it using a reverse set query or something like that.

pet_profile/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (ListView,
                                  DetailView)
from pet_profile.models import PetOwner, Pet, PetPhoto, PetStory

class PetOwnerListView(ListView):
    model = PetOwner
    context_object_name = "owner_list"
    template_name = "home.html"

class PetOwnerDetailView(DetailView):
    model = PetOwner
    context_object_name = "owner"
    template_name = "pet_owner_profile.html"
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['pet_photos'] = {}
        pets = PetOwner.objects.filter(name = "pets")
        for pet in pets:
            context['pet_photos'][pet] = []
            for photo in pet.pet_photos:
                context['pet_photos'][pet] += photo
        # context['pet_photos'] = {pet1: [photo1, photo2, photo3], pet2: [photo1, photo2]}
        return context

class PetListView(ListView):
    model = Pet
    context_object_name = "pet_list"

class PetDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Pet
    context_object_name = "pet"

class PetPhotoListView(ListView):
    model = PetPhoto
    context_object_name = "pet_photo_list"

class PetPhotoDetailView(DetailView):
    model = PetPhoto
    context_object_name = "pet_photo"

class PetStoryListView(ListView):
    model = PetStory
    context_object_name = "pet_story_list"

class PetStoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = PetStory
    context_object_name = "pet_story"
```

Most of the action here is in PetOwnerDetailView. By most I mean all of it.

This is where I tried to make a data structure to store pets and their photos because I didn't know how to access the endogenous data structure of the manytomany field. Also you can't iterate over a manytomanyfield in django.

I stored pets as keys in a dict, and associated photos in respective lists as the values. Don't get too hung up on the syntax of my stuff, I know it's probably wrong, and it is, in fact, like the hundredth iteration of how I've tried to do things (store the data for access in the template downstream). So. Apologies.

I learned that you can't iterate over manytomanyfields, even with .all(), so I tried a filter but I am new to filters, and I don't know if "name" refers to the title of the parameter in the model, or to a parameter named "name". I think it's the latter but the internet isn't good at discerning fine-grained questions like this. Why I'm here.

And the template, finally:
pet_owner_profile.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block header %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {{ owner.name }}
    {{ owner.age }}
    {{ owner.location }}
    {{ owner.profile_photo }}
    {% for pet in owner.pets.all %}
        {{ pet.name }}
        {{ pet.animaltype }}
        {{ pet.age }}
        <!-- context['pet_photos'] = {pet1: [photo1, photo2, photo3], pet2: [photo1, photo2]} -->
        {% for photo in pet_photos.pet.photos %}
            <img src = "{{ photo.photo.url }}">
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

All the weird stuff, like photo.photo.url instead of just photo (wouldn't that be nice), are mostly from suggestions on the internet because I don't ad hoc know how to display an image in django, from a database. Although, photo is the iterable, and .photo is the model parameter. The former is the PetPhoto object, and the latter is the photos parameter. I hope that's clear. .url is something I found on the internet. Yes, I am rationalizing everything, thinking it through, and testing, not blindly, but cautiously.

The second half of this is, whether I am using my static/ directory structure correctly.

So far, I have a static/ folder under the master pet_memorial folder (NOT the project-level pet_memorial sub-folder--nor the pet_profile app folder).

Here are my parameters in settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

I hope that's right but I was hoping someone could correct me if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that **MEDIA_ROOT** and **MEDIA_URL** settings are correctly configured in your **settings.py** file to display the pet photos in the template.

To display the pet photos in a template, you need to pass the pets and their associated photos to the template as context. Since you want to display data from multiple models in one view, so creating a dictionary would be better, like so:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Pet, PetPhoto

def all_pet_photos(request):
    pets = Pet.objects.all()
    pet_data = {}
    for pet in pets:
        pet_data[pet] = PetPhoto.objects.filter(pets=pet)
    context = {'pet_data': pet_data}
    return render(request, 'pet_owner_profile.html', context)
```

Then in your template, you can iterate over the **pet_data** dictionary using a for loop, like so:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Pet Photos</h1>
    {% for pet, photos in pet_data.items %}
        <h2>{{ pet.name }}</h2>
        {% for photo in photos %}
            <img src="{{ photo.photo.url }}" alt="{{ photo.title }}">
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your answer looks very good! It makes sense to me and it is very clean. I see that the dot notation is in fact used in the template and that .url is required at the end of the image src url for the url to function. I have an issue though and that is that the images aren't showing up! I thought they should be in static but I copy pasted them into media. STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, MEDIA_URL)  and static and media are in the root directory same as manage.py.

Comment: I don't know if it is alright to have a class-based view and a function-based view for the same template? Is it okay to have both def all_pet_photos(request) & class PetOwnerDetailView(DetailView)?

Comment: Also the template file should be pet_owner_profile.html (I am displaying all the pets and relevant photos for a given pet owner). I haven't tried the pet profile page yet. I need to work on that still. Work in progress after all! :-)

Comment: @starrtennis I'd recommend you to use this function based view as I mentioned in the Answer, it is much more simple than class based view used by you.

Comment: I changed the function-based view to a class-based view and it is working much better. There may have been some conflict with my code structure the way you had it written out. I modified the code as necessary to accomodate this change to a class-based view and it works almost perfectly! The for loop executes and the dictionary is good the header displays but it shows the image alt title instead of the image. The function based view just didn't work for me. But I will accept the answer! Thank you!

Comment: I am curious--what is the ".url" there for? What does it mean and how does it function?

Comment: @starrtennis the `".url"` is used to retrieve the URL of a particular object or view. This is accomplished through the use of the `reverse()` function, which takes the name of a view and returns its URL. While displaying images it gives the path to the media folder, If you have curiosity, you can also print it to see what's is inside that.

Comment: I printed out the photo.photo.url and it has the path to the image, but it only prints the alt text when the actual img is attempted to be printed. Really weird, I don't get it.

Comment: @starrtennis Did you do this in view of template? Alt is used to show some description about the image, if the image is broken or 404.

Comment: {{ photo.photo.url }} in the template prints out the correct path to the image, which is not corrupt. <img src="{{ photo.photo.url }}" alt="{{ photo.title }}"> displays only the alt text, the product of {{ photo.title }}. I'm not sure what is going on. The image is located in /media/ and the name and path. as I mentioned, are correctly identified by the tag.

Comment: As a side note, the function-based view didn't work because I didn't modify urls.py. I think I could get it to work now, but there is no need in any case, at the moment.

Comment: Currently going through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: I tried serving (locally) the pet dog photo (shade photo) from /pet_memorial/pet_profile/static/ but it appended a six digit ASCII string to each photo I upload from there, rendering using that folder ineffective. I don't know why Django does this. {% load static %} at top of file and <img src="{% static photo.photo.url %}" alt="{{ photo.title }}"> doesn't work. Actually now it is doing that from the /media folder too. I don't get it. The photo.photo.url has the 6 digit tag, but the actual file does not, so it won't find it. I don't get it.

Comment: @MichaelStarr Listen, it's not allowed in Stack Overflow to ask further and further questions on single question, but you can access my GitHub account by going into my Stack Overflow profile, you can share the repo I'd see it ;) My GitHub link https://github.com/sunderamDubey you can share.